# Associate timestamps with working shift starts in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with datetimes/timestamps I need to resample to 8 hours (to know which working shift is concerned with the data based on the timestamps.) I have tried  resample combined with transform, but I can't find the solution ?

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=100, freq='H')
ts = pd.Series({'A':idx}, index=idx)

ts.resample('8H', on='A').agg('first') --> I wan't only the index but associated with each individual timestamps 
ts.resample('8H', on='A').transform('first') --> Can't find the right feature to associate a timestamp to the proper working shift start
```

Any help or re-direction will be appreciated.

Comment: One of the intent is to use to plot boxplots and use the created column as a "group" / "hue"

Comment: `ts.resample('8H').transform('first')` is a start but I think there should be something more elegant